# How to release memory from a PopOverViewController when the controller is removed from a view, ARC

Tags: ios, uitableview, automatic-ref-counting, uipopovercontroller

Hi so I have a popoverviewcontroller with a tableview in it. everytime i press the button to view the popover, some memory is allocated (1024). If i press it multiple times the allocations just grows and grows. Since the app is written in ARC i thought this  would be handled by the automatic. How do i make sure that my popover does infact remove all allocated data when removed, code is attached below:

```
//
//  SettingPopOverViewController.m
//  CodeFriend
//
//  Created by Exjobb on 5/22/13.
//  Copyright (c) 2013 davidkarlsson. All rights reserved.
//

#import "ThemesPopOverViewController.h"

@interface ThemesPopOverViewController ()

@end

@implementation ThemesPopOverViewController
@synthesize tableView;

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {


        themes = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:kRegexHighlightViewThemeArray];
        self.tableView = nil;
        self.tableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 0, self.view.frame.size.width - 40, 350)];
        [self.tableView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
        [self.tableView setDelegate:self];
        [self.tableView setDataSource:self];
        [self.view addSubview:self.tableView];
        int item = [themes indexOfObject:theDelegate.codeView.currentTheme];
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:item inSection:0];
        [self.tableView selectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionNone];

    }

    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;    //count of section
}


- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    //NSLog(@"%d",themes.count);
    return [themes  count];    //count number of row from counting array hear cataGorry is An Array
}



- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
         cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *MyIdentifier = @"MyIdentifier";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:MyIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
                                      reuseIdentifier:MyIdentifier];

        UIView *bgColorView = [[UIView alloc] init];
        [bgColorView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:25/255.0f green:185/255.0f blue:152/255.0f alpha:1.0f]];
        [cell setSelectedBackgroundView:bgColorView];
    }
    [cell.textLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:16]];
    cell.textLabel.text = [themes objectAtIndex: indexPath.row];
    return cell;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    NSLog(@"%d", indexPath.row);
    [theDelegate.codeView setHighlightThemeFromString:[themes objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    [theDelegate removePop];

}

@end
```

I am showing the pop with:

```
-(void) settingAct:(UIButton *)sender{
    if (!popover) {
        ThemesPopOverViewController *newView = [[ThemesPopOverViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SettingPopOverViewController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
        self.popover = [[WEPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:newView];
        [self.popover setContainerViewProperties:[self improvedContainerViewProperties]];
        [self.popover setPopoverContentSize:CGSizeMake(128, 360)];
        [self.popover presentPopoverFromRect:CGRectMake(sender.center.x+12, sender.center.y, 0, 20)
                                      inView:self.window.rootViewController.view
                    permittedArrowDirections:(UIPopoverArrowDirectionUp|UIPopoverArrowDirectionDown|
                                              UIPopoverArrowDirectionLeft|UIPopoverArrowDirectionRight)
                                    animated:YES];


    }else{
        [self removePop];
    }
}
```

The popover is removed using just:

```
-(void) removePop{

    [self.popover dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
    self.popover = nil;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WePopOver if I recall is not ARCified. There is an Arc version at [this link](https://github.com/dhoerl/WEPopover). I don't know for sure but that may be the issue. The other thing you can do is add a log message in all relevant object subclasses, in the dealloc method, so you can observe when the popover is dismissed which objects are NOT released.

Comment: Well that surely helps for starters!